# Tensorflow Lite on Nvidia Jetson

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia-jetson, tensorflow-lite

Has anyone used Tensorflow Lite on any Nvidia Jetson product? I want to use my Jetson Nano for inference and would like to so with tf-lite utilizing the GPU.

Confusingly, [there does not seem to be a Python API for creating a GPU Delegate in tf-lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu_advanced).

Is there are clear reason for this?

Is the alternative to use the full Tensorflow library (I would prefer not use the Nvidia TensorRT engine)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have tried to use tf lite on Jetson Nano before.

You can refer to my previous article on Medium (PS: I am sorry that the article was written in Chinese.)

This article is about how to set up the TF Lite Environment on Jetson Nano

**Notice：**

You should change the following command according to your own environment.

`pip3 install https://dl.google.com/coral/python/tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp36-cp36m-linux_aarch64.whl`

**Setting up TF lite on Jetson Nano:**
https://yanwei-liu.medium.com/tflite-on-jetson-nano-c480fdf9ac2

Comment: Please read the 'Provide context for links' part of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer , and edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I too was able to run tflite, but there does not seem to be way yet to take advantage of the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

in case it is of interest to you to use inference with C++ you can compile TFlite 2.4.1 on your Jetson device like I did on the Xavier NX:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cmake curl
$ wget -O tensorflow.zip https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/archive/v2.4.1.zip
$ unzip tensorflow.zip
$ mv tensorflow-2.4.1 tensorflow
$ cd tensorflow
$ ./tensorflow/lite/tools/make/download_dependencies.sh
$ ./tensorflow/lite/tools/make/build_aarch64_lib.sh
```

After that you will also have to install the TF lite flat buffers like this:

```
$ cd ./tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/downloads/flatbuffers
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make -j
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig
```

After that you find the library here `tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/tools/make/gen/linux_aarch64/libtensorflow-lite.a`

You can build your inference application against that like this

```
gcc -llibtensorflow-lite.a -ledgetpu main.cpp
```

You will also need to install libedgetpu.so like shown on Coral.ai

Best
Alexander

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! How did you call gpu delegates with C++ on Jetson in your case?